# VB.NET loop timer, multiple "IF" conditions

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, timer

Writing the title to try and explain my query I think was harder than the problem I'm actually facing :) - Anyway on to the question.

So I have a 20 second timer but I want two different things to happen on the first and second 10 seconds. Specifically to change the active tab.

So I thought to myself I'll just write an if Statement in the timer tick event that if it = 10 seconds to change to the second tab and when it hits 0 to switch back to the first, then to restart the timer.

Below is my code but nothing happens, I think the problem lies with reading the current remaining time.

```
Private timeLeft2 As Integer

Private Sub timerCountdown2()
        timeLeft2 = 20
    End Sub

Private Sub tabTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tabTimer.Tick

        If timeLeft2 = 10 Then
            TabControlVertical1.SelectTab(1)
        End If

        If timeLeft2 = 0 Then
            TabControlVertical1.SelectTab(0)
            tabTimer.Stop()
            tabTimer.Start()
        End If

    End Sub
```

The properties of my timer are enabled = true and Interval = 1000

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `timeLeft2` is always 20, you never change this value.

Comment: I should add something like timeLeft -= 1 ?

Comment: If you set the timer to trigger the Tick event every 20 seconds how is it possible to execute code in that event when are passed just 10 seconds? Your logic has a flaw or I don't understand your question

Comment: You should set the timer for 10 seconds. It sounds like you then just need a boolean variable, to switch the tabs.

Comment: I'm using 20 seconds because when it reaches 10 I want it to change and then at 0 to change again, effectively making it every 10 seconds something happens, if that makes sense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because if the timer is set for 20 seconds then nothing will happen after 10 seconds.

Comment: I am now getting more and more confused, let me look at using a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the timer to trigger the Tick event every 10 seconds, not every 20 (or 1 as by your edit above).

Every time the `Tick` event is triggered, you look at the value of a global boolean variable. 
If this variable is true you execute the code reserved for the first 10 seconds and invert the value of the boolean. When the timer triggers again, you execute the code for the second case and invert again the value of the boolean

So, somewhere in your code or in the designer set the `tabTimer` interval to 10 seconds

```
tabTimer.Interval = 10000
```

and declare a global boolean variable  (In the same forms class probably)

```
Private tabSwitcher as Boolean = True
```

Now the Tick event could be written as:
(no need to stop the timer if this process needs to continue)

```
Private Sub tabTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tabTimer.Tick

    If tabSwitcher = True Then
        TabControlVertical1.SelectTab(1)
    else 
        TabControlVertical1.SelectTab(0)
    End If
    tabSwitcher = Not tabSwitcher
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you are asking:

1. do something in 10 timer ticks - timer set to 1000
2. do something else 10 timer ticks later
3. repeat

Try this

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static ct As Integer = 0
    ct += 1
    If ct = 10 Then
        'do 10 stuff here
        Debug.WriteLine("10")
    ElseIf ct = 20 Then
        'do 20 stuff here
        Debug.WriteLine("20")

        'then reset ct <<<<<<<<<<<<
        ct = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Friend Class timerCtrl : Inherits Timer

    Private ReadOnly tickFunc As EventHandler = Nothing

    Friend Sub New(ByRef theFunc As EventHandler, ByVal theInterval As Integer, Optional ByVal autoStart As Boolean = True)
        tickFunc = theFunc
        Interval = theInterval
        AddHandler Tick, tickFunc
        If (autoStart) Then Start()
    End Sub

    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            RemoveHandler Tick, tickFunc
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

End Class

Friend Class TabClass

    Private timerStep As Boolean = False
    Private timerTabs As timerCtrl = Nothing

    Friend Sub New()
        timerTabs = New timerCtrl(AddressOf timerTabsTick, 10000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub timerTabsTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        timerStep = Not timerStep
        If timerStep Then
            ' condition 1
        Else
            ' condition 2
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

a simple timer helper class for abstraction. to kill the timer, not just .Stop it, use timerTabs.Dispose(). eliminates the need to detach the event handler separately.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me that your timer is never getting to the value you are asking for in the if statements due to the fact that you have set the timer to the value of 20.

Also, I've use visual basics and am not to sure but doens't it need to be timeleft2.value?

Also, by stoping and starting the timer, it isn't actually restarting the timer, when you stop it say on 15 secs, and the restart, the timer restarts from 15 secs.

Try this.

```
    If timeLeft2.Value = 10 Then
        TabControlVertical1.SelectTab(1)
        else if timeLeft2.Value = 0 Then
        TabControlVertical1.SelectTab(0)
        tabTimer.Stop()
        timeLeft2.value = 0
        tabTimer.Start()
    End If
```